# See if a users has write access to a git repository in TFS 2017?

Tags: git, tfs

Is there a way in PowerShell to see if a given AD user has write access to one or all Git repositories hosted in a TFS 2017 Project?

Based on below answer I can now list the groups a user is in with:

```
& $tfssecurity /imx $user /collection:$tfsCollection
```

Next I am trying to list permissions for one of those groups using **tf.exe**, e.g.:

```
& $tf permission  /group:"Project Valid Users" /collection:$tfsCollection
```

That gives:

Multiple identities found matching 'Project Valid Users'. Please specify one of the following identities:

```
- [Sample]\Project Valid Users (vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/04f6bd69-9382-43de-8a5a-2cd784ac39a3\Project Valid Users)
- [Sample2]\Project Valid Users (vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/f98df8fa-f270-4750-a73b-3a3082aaa6c9\Project Valid Users)
```

I have then tried to adjust the call with:

```
& $tf permission  /group:"[Sample]\Project Valid Users" /collection:$tfsCollection
```

But that gives the error:

```
The item $/ does not exist at the specified version, or you do not have permission to access it.
```

Am I missing some escape characters rules here?

Comment: Are the Git / TFS privileges being delegated by AD?

Comment: Some groups are defined in AD and then included in TFS groups. As long as the AD group is included in a TFS group that has git repository access it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of **permission** for each repo in TFS. You could find this through *web portal--version control--the repo--security*

[image]

However, there is no such a permission directly called **write** in the list, the most related which should be **Contribute**. For more detail description of each permission, please refer this--**[Git permissions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/git-permissions-before-2017)**

To achieve what you need, you could list permission and display identity information for a specified group  with [tf Permission Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command) &[TFSSecurity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd). Finally do a match if the user has related permission or in a group with enough permission.

Comment: I have adjusted my original question based on your suggestions but the tf.exe call fails.

Comment: @u123 Did you use the format `/group:[teamproject]\developers`  and also try to run the same command through command prompt? To use the permission command, you must have the **Manipulate security settings permission** set to Allow for the folders being modified, be a member of the Team Foundation Administrators security group, or be a system administrator on the local computer (Windows Administrator security group).